# UILabel in TableViewCell expands height when it shouldn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have UILabel in a TableViewCell that can have multiple lines of text. I'm using auto layout and expecting the cell to expand it's height as appropriate. It works fine most of the time, but something strange happens when the text in the UILabel is almost at the width of the label. The label seems to expand it's height prematurely.

**UPDATE:** I've uploaded the sample project to github:
https://github.com/fwaddle/TestBadHeight

As seen below, the first cell shouldn't be larger than the second cell.

[image: The Tableview]

Top Label Constraints:

[image: Top Label Constraints]

Sub Label Constraints:

[image: Sub Label Constraints]

Info Button Constraints

[image: Info Button Constraints]

Comment: what about the cell's `height` which provided by the delegate class?

Comment: I see something very similar in my app, and it only happens on the iOS7 simulator (I don't have a device with iOS7 anymore). Same contraints code on iOS8 (device or simulator), and it works fine.

Comment: Holex: I'm not specifying the height because I'm making use of the UIDynamics auto cell height functionality.

Comment: Koen: I am running this on 8.1 in the simulator and on a device with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with the way you configured the labels. The first thing is that you modified the `Content Hugging Priority` for the `SublLabel` to 252 instead of the default 251. This causes the default behavior of the UILabel to change (meaning it won't be resized to exactly fit it's content).

Once you modify that, your constraints will have some conflicts, because it cannot satisfy all at the same time, the static cell height and the verticals constraints that define the cell height.

Therefore, you will need to either change the size of the cell in the storyboard so that it is correct for this particular case (I tried it out and the correct height, to satisfy the constraints is 73) or to lower the priority for one of the constraints (let's say the bottom one from the `SubLabel` to the `ContentView`). 
The result should be the same and your labels height should be calculated correctly.

Hope this solves your problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Catalina, You were indeed correct. I really should have better understood Compression and Hugging priorities.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sizeToFit in the UILabel ? This may cause the cell to resize to fit the number 5 and can't satisfy your trailing constrain.